# for(;...) or while(...) flow control?

Tags: c, for-loop, while-loop

Which one, 1 or 2, is better in any way (whatever can be considered better)? Are they exactly the same?

```
void method1(char **var1) {

  //the last element of var1 is NULL

  char **var2 = var1;
  int count = 0;

  //1
  for (; *var2; (*var2)++, count++);

  //2
  while(*var2) {
    (*var2)++;
    count++;
  }
}
```

Comment: A descent compiler won't make any difference. Hang on..a bunch of assemblies is probably going to come as answers.

Comment: by the way, i think what you mean is `(var2)++` instead of `(*var2)++`

Comment: @AlexanderSupertramp: Then what is the code supposed to do? Increment the pointer `var1[0]` until it overflows to zero?

Comment: Downvoting *only* because the question lacks the description of what the code example should achieve and at the same time the OP is not happy with a fix that would make it work as a casual reader would expect. Would be nice to fix that.

Comment: @PavelŠimerda, I'll be able to get over it.

Comment: The question is put on hold because it is reportedly primarily opinion-based, but (1) the original code is buggy and at least the accepted answer shows what's wrong and how to fix it and (2) the usage of `for` loop over `while` loop has very clear reasons (separation of the looping logic) and the answer presents those reasons in a way that the reader can himself evaluate when the reasons apply and when they don't. I don't think the question is opinion based in general, just the corner cases are, and that IMO doesn't justify the on hold status.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would prefer the for loop, if you initialize var2 as the first argument of the for loop, i.e.

```
for(char **var2 = var1; *var2; var2++)
```

because then all conditions (initial, terminal, increment) are located in one place

I would also prefer to make the test explicit, i.e.,

```
for(char **var2 = var1; *var2 != NULL; var2++)
```

because it makes the terminal condition more visible.

Next: I would not place `count++` in the for loop, because if count is not modified inside the loop it is redundant and can be calculated from var2 - var 1. If count is modified inside the loop it should be done at a single spot.

But I assume this is a matter of taste only.

Comment: `*var2;` is perfectly explicit. Adding `!= NULL` is simply clutter.

Comment: I know, but for him it was not explicit enough since he added a comment... - you may drop that part.

Comment: why didn't you add "count++" to "for"?

Comment: Huh? The comment documents, that the array passed has got some sentinel value, not to tell how the conditions tested later are evaluated, I think.

Comment: @AlexanderSupertramp: Put `count++` in the loop body. Don't cram code into the `for` statement that isn't related to loop control.

Comment: @AlexanderSupertramp: It feels redundant to me to have two loop indices. It may also be a source of error if the two become inconsistent. I made a comment on count++ in my answer.

Comment: Your code still increments the very pointer that is tested for being NULL, so the loop will either not run at all or will run until overflow occurs.

Comment: @PavelŠimerda: I just copied his code (the code in the question). It a bug in his code, I assume.

Comment: why do you increment `var2++` instead of `(*var2)++`?

Comment: @AlexanderSupertramp: Because incrementing target of the pointer and then checking it for being NULL is a nonsense as pointed out in almost all answers and in the comments as well. Read the accepted answer carefully as there's a detailed explanation of this.

Answer (score 2):

you could examine the asm output at different optimization levels with your compiler... or just not worry about stuff that is semantically the same...

```
...

LBB0_1:                                 ## =>This Inner Loop Header: Depth=1
    movq    -16(%rbp), %rax
    cmpq    $0, (%rax)
    je  LBB0_4
## BB#2:                                ##   in Loop: Header=BB0_1 Depth=1
    jmp LBB0_3
LBB0_3:                                 ##   in Loop: Header=BB0_1 Depth=1
    movq    -16(%rbp), %rax
    movq    (%rax), %rcx
    addq    $1, %rcx
    movq    %rcx, (%rax)
    movl    -20(%rbp), %edx
    addl    $1, %edx
    movl    %edx, -20(%rbp)
    jmp LBB0_1
LBB0_4:
    ...


.subsections_via_symbols
```

method2:

```
...

LBB0_1:                                 ## =>This Inner Loop Header: Depth=1
    movq    -16(%rbp), %rax
    cmpq    $0, (%rax)
    je  LBB0_3
## BB#2:                                ##   in Loop: Header=BB0_1 Depth=1
    movq    -16(%rbp), %rax
    movq    (%rax), %rcx
    addq    $1, %rcx
    movq    %rcx, (%rax)
    movl    -20(%rbp), %edx
    addl    $1, %edx
    movl    %edx, -20(%rbp)
    jmp LBB0_1
LBB0_3:
    ...


.subsections_via_symbols
```

Comment: gcc -S 1.c -o 1.s is the command given, you can examine with optimization flags

Comment: you will see that they are basically the same, one ends up with another label... but it is just a jump to the next line, would have just fallen through anyway.

Comment: Why is the trivial jump not optimized out?

Comment: no optimization level was specified

Comment: Thanks, just want to make sure. So I guess your answer is one of three valid ones, just from different points of view.

Answer (score 2):

### Purpose of the code in question

Your code seems to be entirely wrong as it increments the target of `var2` pointer, which also serves for ending the loop. You cannot expect an incrementing value to reach zero. I will assume that (1) you wanted to increment the temporary pointer to iterate over a list (technically an array) of character strings and (2) that you expect a NULL pointer as a sentinel.

### Detailed explanation of the pointer incrementation issue

So what is the logic of the code we are writing? It takes an array of strings (lines in a file, list of names, etc...), counts the items, and then does whatever else you need to do. The input argument is represented by a pointer to pointer to char, which can be a bit confusing for the beginner. Pointers are used for multiple purposes in C and one is to point to the first item of a list (technically array). This is the case of the `list` pointer (type `char **`) which points to an array of pointers (type `char *` each) which in turn point to an array of byte/character values (type `char` each).

Therefore you need to increment a local `char **` pointer to iterate over the items and a temporary `char *` pointer to iterate over characters of an item. If you just want to read data, you must never increment anything else than local (temporary) variables. Incrementing `*item` is nonsense and would alter the data in a bad way (the pointer would point to the second character instead of the first one), and checking the incremented pointer for being NULL is a double nonsense.

In other words, the idiom of iterating over an array using a temporary pointer requires the following actions:

1. Increment the temporary pointer (and nothing else) at each step.
2. Check the *target* of the pointer (and not the address it points to) for the sentinel value.

### Corrected code examples

Using C99 syntax, you probably wanted to do something like:

```
void method1(char **list) {
    size_t count = 0;
    for (char **item = list; *item; item++)
        count++;
    ...
}
```

The older syntax is forcing you to do:

```
void method1(char **list) {
    char **item;
    size_t count = 0;

    for (item = list; *item; item++)
        count++;
    ...
}
```

A more intuitive version for people not fluent in pointers:

```
void method1(char **list) {
    size_t count = 0;
    for (size_t i = 0; list[i]; i++)
        count++;
    ...
}
```

Note: The `count` is redundant as its value is kept the same as the value of `i`, so you could just do `for (; list[count]; count++)` with an empty body or `while (list[count]) count++;`.

A real function to just count the items would be:

```
size_t get_size(char **list)
{
    int count = 0;
    for (char **item = list; *item; item++)
        count++;
    return count;
}
```

Of course it could be simplified to (borrowing from other answer):

```
size_t get_size(char **list)
{
    int count = 0;
    for (; *list; list++)
        count++;
    return count;
}
```

Thanks to very specific circumstances where (1) it's easy to merge the *condition* and the *increment* and (2) you're not using the current item in the body, it can be turned to:

```
size_t get_size(char **list)
{
    int count = 0;
    while (*list++)
        count++;
    return count;
}
```

### Attempt to answer the `for` versus `while` dilemma

While technically the `while` and `for` loops are equivalent, the `for` loop expresses the iteration idiom *way* better, as it keeps the iteration logic separate from the rest of the code and thus also makes it more reusable, i.e. you can use the same `for` header with a different body for any other iterative action on the list.

### Bad usage of the `for` loop in the original code

There are a number of things that should be considered discouraged:

1) Don't modify the object from the for loop header.

```
for (... ; ...; (*item)++)
    ...
```

Any code matching the above patter modifies the target object instead of performing the looping logic, whenever `item` is a temporary pointer to the actual data.

2) Don't decouple any non-looping code from the for loop header.

```
char **item = list;
...
for (; *item; *item++)
    count++;
```

The assignment before the for loop seems out of place. If you copy-pasted the header of the for loop to iterate again over all list items, the list would seem empty because of the omitted initialization.

3) Don't perform any per-item actions in the *increment* of the for loop header.

```
for (char **item = list; *item++, count++)
    ;
```

The `count++` here doesn't help the looping at all, instead it performs an actual action (counting one item). If you copy-pasted the header of the for loop and added an actual body, the `count` would get modified.

4) Don't use non-descriptive for arguments, use simple names for temporary variables.

```
for (char **var2 = var1; *var2; var2++)
    count++;
```

The two variables differ in their purpose, yet their names are almost the same, only distinguished by a number. How exactly you name them is a matter of context and preference.

Note: Some people also prefer explicit comparison to NULL instead of relying on boolean evaluation of pointers. I'm not one of them, though. Stack Exchange seems to highlight `list` as a keyword but I don't think there's such a keyword in C or C++.

Comment: Would the downvoter care to explain his reasons or it was just a revenge for downvoting something else? In the former case, I'm ready to fix the answer.

Comment: no, no they probably don't... they are just haters.

Comment: why do you increment `item++` and not `(*item)++` in the first case where `item` is a double pointer?

Comment: @AlexanderSupertramp: It takes a bit of imagination or even drawing on a paper to understand the logic of using pointers to work with arrays in C. Added a rather thorough explanation but you still need to work towards understanding the memory pointer concepts.

Comment: @AlexanderSupertramp: Were you aware that the input argument represents a list of strings (as also suggested by the comment that says `NULL` is the last element / which is incorrect anyway, as NULL doesn't represent an actual element)?

Comment: `Incrementing *item is nonsense and would alter the data in a bad way` - that's what I said to Vlad from Moscow.

Comment: `size_t get_size(char **list)
{
    int count = 0;
    for (; *list; list++)` - why do you increment the parameter if you said it's nonsense?

Comment: I'm not. It is nonsense to increment `*item`, the correct way to iterate over a list of strings is to iterate `item`, in the code example I'm correctly incrementing `list` which is equivalent to incrementing `item` (when you don't need to keep the original pointer). Nonsense would be if I incremented `*list`. And no, you didn't say that to Vlad, instead almost everyone told that to you.

Comment: Are you aware that both `list` and `item` are local variables and thus it's not important whether you change *list* unless you want to use it again in the same function? That's why I always use `item = list` in examples of a custom function that I expect to be extended and only modify the `list` local variable in a function that shows you can avoid the second local variable when you don't need to use the original value in the rest of the function.

Comment: More ghost downvoters?

Answer (score 1):

Probably both are same, compiler should not make any difference.

Comment: It's true, but doesn't necessarily answer the question. Code is written for both compilers and humans.

Answer (score 0):

First of all the both loops are wrong. They have no sense. I think you mean the following

```
int count = 0;

while ( *var1++ ) ++count;
```

It is the loop I would use.

Or if you want that var1 would not be changed then

```
int count = 0;

for ( char **p = var1; *p; ++p ) ++count;
```

Also you could write

```
char **p = var1;

while ( *p ) ++p;

int count = p - var1;
```

Comment: Why would I change var1 by ++? I don't want to change it.

Comment: `var1` is a `char **` so `(*var2)++` may be exactly what he meant.

Comment: @Alexander Supertramp See my updated post.

Comment: @Carey Gregory The loops have no sense.

Comment: What did you update? There is still *var1++ in while loop.

Comment: @Alexander Supertramp It is clear enough what i changed.

Comment: While I added a more extensive answer, the current version of this answer seems to be entirely correct. The first code snippet seems to benefit from the fact that local variable `var1` is already initialized and assumes that we won't need its value after the loop.

Comment: The second snippet is equivalent to the first one in my answer. An the third one is an elegant way to do it without a counter. It may also be handy when there's more pointer based logic in the code, for example when working with buffers and a set of pointers (e.g. beginning of the buffer, beginning of data, end of data, end of the buffer).

Comment: @VladfromMoscow I considered reusing parts of your answer to improve mine, but I think that yours is a quick summary of what can be done, useful for experts, while mine is more about providing guidance to a beginner. So let's keep those as separate answers.

Comment: @Pavel Šimerda This your comment has no any sense. The guidance is one: it shall be correct. And my answer showed correct approaches.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow: I don't follow.

Comment: Why would I change var1 by ++? I don't want to change it.

Comment: @Alexander Supertramp Why are you asking the same question when I showed already how to write the loop without changing of var1?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow, because you still didn't answer it.

Comment: Ну ты и гамнюк, Владик.

Comment: @Alexander Supertramp What is the problem? Can not you read what is written in my post? Try to reread it one more.

Answer (score -1):

you better make the loop conditional statement more stronger and explicit to avoid bugs and infinity loops. which one is better depends in your logic and code, "for" loops is faster and easier but if you want to make a loop which needs more logic then use "while" loop.

Comment: The loop conditional is perfectly fine. There's nothing about it that would lead to bugs or infinite loops. And I seriously doubt that `for` is faster than `while`.

Comment: bu the way the while loop output will be different from the for loop one, because in the beginning of for loop if the statement is true then it will make count++; first then execute (*var2)++; but in while the opposed thing will happened.

Comment: i knew that fact of "for loops" from assembly language and i may be wrong here :D i just wanted to help you with what i know .